# When is the deadline for candidacies for Parliament for the UK election this year?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, house-of-commons

In the context of Nigel Farage threatening to contest or not some seats, when is the deadline for the candidacies for seats to be announced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Candidates have until 4pm on Thursday 14 November to file their nomination papers with their local councils.

Assuming that no objections are made to any nominations, councils will be expected to publish a Statement of Persons Nominated for each constituency at 5pm on this same day.

Source: [Electoral Commission](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/i-am-a/candidate-or-agent/uk-parliamentary-general-election-great-britain)