# Can candidates for MP seats "stand down" in a formal way after declaring candidacy?

Tags: united-kingdom, election

As the Guardian [reported](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/nov/08/nigel-farage-softens-stance-in-attempt-to-form-pact-with-tories)

> Farage began the party’s election campaign last week saying he would put up candidates across the country unless Johnson abandoned his Brexit deal and formed a leave alliance. [...]
>
> Farage offered Johnson a deal last week in which his party would stand down in seats where the Tory candidate believed in a no-deal or “clean Brexit” and would want to abandon Johnson’s deal. In return, he wanted his party to have a free run at Labour heartland seats.

I suppose [there is a deadline](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47533/when-is-the-deadline-for-candidacies-for-parliament-for-the-uk-election-this-yea) for entering candidacies, but is there one for withdrawing from the election thereafter? Can candidates formally drop out of the race any time thereafter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The deadline for withdrawing a candidacy is the same as the deadline for filing nomination papers.  For this election, the deadline for both is 4pm on Thursday 14 November.

Source: [Electoral Commission](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/i-am-a/candidate-or-agent/uk-parliamentary-general-election-great-britain)